# Cline wrong width in table

Tags: tables, cline

I would like to create a table with different `\vline` and `\hline` width. But, when I use `\cline` in this table it draws wrong lines in places, where `\setlength` used in header of tabular. How can I fix it?

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption {text} \label{tab:lb3}
    \begin{tabular}
        {@{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline~}c|c|c|c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline~}c|c|c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline~}c|c|c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline~}c|c|c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}} 
        \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em} 
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\

        \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em} 
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}}{\multirow{3}*{A}} \\
        \cline {1-10}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}}{} \\
        \cline{1-9}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}}{} \\
        \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your definition of the thick vertical lines. Here is a correct (and shorter) code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow, array, caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption {text} \label{tab:lb3}
\begin{tabular}
    {!{\vrule width 0.2em}c|*4{c|c|c|c!{\vrule width 0.2em}}}
    \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}}{\multirow{3}*{A}} \\
    \cline {1-10}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}}{} \\
    \cline{1-9}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{~\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2em}\vline}}{} \\
    \specialrule{0.2em}{0em}{0em}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]